# Stream Hash Map using Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

Example SQL Result

```
dataResult
Code    Amt      TotalAmtPerCode
A1      4           0
A1      4           0
B1      4           0
B1      5           0
A1      6           0
```

with this result
i would like to ask on how to compute the TotalAmtPerCode
The expected result should be

```
Code    Amt      TotalAmtPerCode
A1      4           14
A1      4           14
B1      4           9
B1      5           9
A1      6           14
```

sample code

```
for (Map<String, Object> data: dataResult) {
    Long total = ComputeTotalAmount(dataResult,data.get(DBColumn.Code.name();
    container.setTotalAmtPerCode(total);
}
```

function that computes the total amount

```
private static long ComputeTotalAmount(List<Map<String, Object>> list, String code) {
    Long total = 0;
    for (Map<String, Object> data: dataResult) {
        if (code.equals(data.get(DBColumn.Code.name()))) {
            total = total+Long.valueOf(data.get(DBColumn.Code.name()).toString)
        }
    }        
}
```

This one is working fine but I would like to ask for an optimization on this code. Because if I would loop 10,000 records, it would check 1st record for the Code then reiterate the 10k to find the same Code and get the amount on that code and sum it all then it would check the 2nd record and so-on.

Comment: why not change your query to return the info you need?

Comment: Why don't you group the data by `Code`? Is that requirement?

Comment: Map<String, Integer> sum = dataresult.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(result::getCode, Collectors.summingInt(result::getAmt)));
Above code group by code with total amount per code .

Comment: Is it possible just tune sql request? like `select sum(TotalAmtPerCode), Code from Table group by Code `

Comment: Were the answers not helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

As far as I see you need to group the sum of `TotalAmtPerCode` values by the `Code`. There exist a method [`Stream::collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) to transform the values to the desired output using [`Collectors::groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector which groups the `Stream<T>` into `Map<K, V>` where `V` is a collection.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = dataresult.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(                                             // Group to Map
         d -> d.get(DBColumn.Code.name()),                                      // Key is the code
         Collectors.summingInt(d -> d.get(DBColumn.TotalAmtPerCode.name())))); // Value is the sum
```

Note:

- You might need to edit `d -> d.get(DBColumn.Code.name())` and `d.get(DBColumn.TotalAmtPerCode.name())` according to your needs to get the `Code` and `TotalAmtPerCode` - I dont know the data model.
- I assume the `TotalAmtPerCode` is `int`. Otherwise, use [`Collectors.summingLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Collectors.groupingBy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
Map<String, Long> collect = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        p -> p.getFirst(),
        Collectors.summingLong(p -> p.getSecond())
    )
);
```

This groups the input by some classifier (here it's `p -> p.getFirst()`, this will be probably something like `data.get(DBColumn.Code.name())` in your case) and summarizes the values (`p -> p.getSecond()`, which must be changed to something like `Long.valueOf(data.get(DBColumn.Code.name()).toString)`).

Note: `getFirst()` and `getSecond()` are methods from `org.springframework.data.util.Pair`.

Example:

```
List<Pair<String, Long>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Pair.of("A1", 1L));
list.add(Pair.of("A1", 2L));
list.add(Pair.of("B1", 1L));

Map<String, Long> collect = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        p -> p.getFirst(),
        Collectors.summingLong(p -> p.getSecond())
    )
);
System.out.println(collect);
```

Output:

```
{A1=3, B1=1}
```

Comment: This is different than OP's expected

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn He gets a lookup map where he can get the values per `Code`.